# Hadoop Nodemanager failing with error Can't get group information

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, nodemanager

I have kerberos configured Apache hadoop(2.8.5) installed. NameNode, DataNode and ResourceManager is running fine, but Nodemanager is failing to start with error:

```
Can't get group information for hadoop#configured value of yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group - Success.
```

file permissions:

```
container-executor.cfg: -rw------- 1 root hadoop
container-executor: ---Sr-s--- 1 root hadoop
```

container-executor.cfg

```
yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/hadoop/data/yarn/local
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop#configured value 
of yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group
banned.users=hdfs,yarn,mapred,bin,root#comma separated list of users who can not run applications
min.user.id=1000#Prevent other super-users
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "#configured value" from the configuration file? Is that a comment? The error appears to say that group "hadoop#configured" doesn't exist. I assume you'd want the group to be named "hadoop".

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for pointing out the issue. I was able to start NodeManager after removing the comment from that line.

Comment: No problem, I've just posted an answer for that.

Comment: can you accept the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the comment:

> #configured value

from the configuration line:

> yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group

on the **container-executor.cfg** file

It should looke like this:

```
yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/hadoop/data/yarn/local
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop
of yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group
banned.users=hdfs,yarn,mapred,bin,root
min.user.id=1000
```

This configuration file has had historical problem with spaces, comments, etc..